# MongoDB and Robo 3T - Error "Can't output mapReduce results to internal DB admin" / "Location31321"

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, robo3t

I am currently learning how to handle MongoDB.

Unfortunately I am not able to execute a mapReduce function and I absolutely didn't find any information about the error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Ja7.png)

errmsg: "Can't output mapReduce results to internal DB admin"

codeName: "Location31321"

Is there someone who knows what I could do to solve this problem?

This is my code (my colleagues don't have any problems with it):

```
db.courses.mapReduce(
    function(){emit(this.course, this.hours);},
    function(key, hours) {return Array.sum(hours)},
    {
        query: {semester: 1},
        out: "totals"
    }
)
db.totals.find()
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Connect to any database other than `admin`.

Comment: Now it worked! I just had to create a new database... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Instead of doing "use admin" I switched to a database with another name and it worked for me.

with "use admin" :

```
> db.Eleves.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "total_masculin"});
Error: map reduce failed:{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Can't output mapReduce results to internal DB admin",
        "code" : 31321,
        "codeName" : "Location31321"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.mapReduce@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1093:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Switching db :

```
> use labo1
switched to db labo1
```

and after recreating my collection in this db :

```
> db.Eleves.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "total_masculin"});
{ "result" : "total_masculin", "ok" : 1 }
```